# Changing default projection in ArcPad 10

Tags: coordinate-system, arcpad

Is there a way to set a default projection in ArcPad 10?

The only way I know is by creating a quickProject based on a project that contains a shapefile with the same projection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can edit the Default Configuration Files (ArcPad.apx)
as it is an .xml you can edit this in notepad++

**ArcPadPrefs.apx** is the one you should edit

(backup your default file first!)

The other way is to set your config files
ArcPad includes two datum configuration files, **Transforms.dbf** and **DefaultTransforms.dbf**, which are located in the ArcPad “System” folder. These files can be modified to add datum transformations as well as to override the default datum transformations within ArcPad

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcpad/10.0/help/index.html#/A_quick_guide_to_ArcPad_customization_files/00s100000075000000/

Answer (score 1):

You can see which projection your map is in by opening "Map Properties" in the "Quick Action Menu" (Big Blue Button). Your projection is on the last tab in this dialog and should be set to WGS84 as a default. To change the projection of the map, open the "Table of Contents" and click on the "Projection" icon (folder and globe) at the top of the stack on the right-hand side. Navigate to "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\ArcPad10.0\Coordinate System" and pick your preferred projection. You can now set this projection as the new default projection or use it once in your current project, whichever you prefer!

Answer (score 1):

If you can source a copy of the PRJ file that contains the string for your required default projection, copy this to your mobile devices My Documents\My ArcPad folder.
Rename it as ArcPad.prj and the next time ArcPad is started it will update its default to the new default.

Also Step 2 of http://www.fs.fed.us/database/gps/arcpad7/index.htm gives a brief overview of how to change the map projection.
If you change the projection via this method, ArcPad will also ask if you wnat to use this as the default projection. Tapping [Yes] will set the new projection as the new default projection.